# XBee is suddenly not receiving anything after I updated Destination mac address

Tags: console, serial-port, serial-communication, xbee

[image]

Hello. I am using XBee for serial communication. I majorly use it from python.

However, after I changed the destination mac address of the XBee, it suddenly does not receive anything. When I send something, the TXD led blinks, however, RXD led never blinks.

My first guess was checking everything in the XCTU software. I re-installed firmware (newest) and I rosetted the destination mac address and then I checked whether it is using AT mode. (It is using AT (transparent mode.)

If my knowledge is correct, it should show something in the console log to the other side if I type something there. Is there any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: I am using XBee PRO 900HP 200K with XBP9B-DM firmware.

Comment: Not a programming question.  Vote to close.